# I can't convert a flat link to a dynamic link through my .htaccess file

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache2

***EDIT:***

The default installation of Apache2 on a Ubuntu system seems to be completely locked down. This also affects the `.htaccess` files as these aren't allowed to overwrite anything from the default configuration.

However, editing the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file did grant my `.htaccess` files enough privileges to do what I wanted to do:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www

    <Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews

        # Modify this from "None" to "All" (or any other suitable value)
-->     AllowOverride None

        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
    ...
```

---

***EDIT:***

This is what my .htaccess looks like as of now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(.+)$ $1-$2.php
```

---

***ORIGIN:***

I found several how-to's about this but I can't get it right (Yes, I'm that tragically stupid).

I would like to translate this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/flat/link?a=b&c=d
```

To this:

```
http://www.mydomain.com/flat-link.php?a=b&c=d
```

As of now I only get a stupid `404` complaining about `The requested URL /flat/link was not found on this server.`

Worth mentioning is that the `404` actually is right; there is no file-structure like `/flat/link` in the www-root, hence I will translate a fictional path to an actual one (as the `flat-link.php` file exists). I've been told that this isn't necessarily the most beautiful architecture but it is a valid scenario as I don't want my file structure to match my REST-api.

Comment: Have you put the `.htaccess` file in the webroot?

Comment: @Lekensteyn: Yes, and I've verified that accessing "the real path" directly (i.e `http://www.mydomain.com/flat-link?a=b&c=d`) gives the expected response. However, accessing the fictional path ( `http://www.mydomain.com/flat/link?a=b&c=d`) throws a `404` at me :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.*` matches everything, try making it less greedy by appending a `?` to it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/(.+)$ $1-$2.php
```

If this does not work, try matching everything except for a slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+)$ $1-$2.php
```

Comment: Both suggested regular expressions work but only after some digging-and-mining: Installing Apache2 on Ubuntu is easy and so, but the web server seems to be tied down to the borders of the ridiculous. *Everything* is disabled by default. That includes the .htaccess files as well. Editing the `/etc/apache2/sites-available/default` file according to the edited answer unleashed the apache2-fury (and your suggestions made me the master of it) :-)

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed a typo in my previous comment. It should say "...according to the edited **question**..." (and not *answer* as I wrote)

Answer (score 0):

Why just dont' put this in httpd.conf (maybe .htaccess too can work)

```
DefaultType application/x-httpd-php
DirectoryIndex index index.html
```

This will tell apache files without extension (DefaultType) must be interpreted by PHP.

So you can rename your `link.php` to `link`

Comment: This is actually the solution that seems most clear to the naked, untrained eye. There is, however, a small caveat with it: It's not guaranteed that one has access to `httpd.conf`-file (which most likely is the case when a web hotel is hosting your site).

Comment: I tried to add your suggested lines as well to my `.htaccess` file (with a slight modification to fit my needs), but the `404` was still present. I would actually have liked your solution more since there is no regular expressions involved in it. It seems much clearer and easier to understand, unfortunately it didn't work for me though...

Comment: i believe you have putted a php file called "link" in a directory called "flat" if you want that working `/flat/link`?

Answer (score 0):

You should probably specify `RewriteBase` directive for the reasons specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778681/htaccess-rewriterule-adds-drive-path-to-url/5807997#5807997).

Comment: Your tip is valid as of reading the documentation but the RewriteBase doesn't seem to make any difference for me, neither for better nor for worse (I don't know why, though).